# How to get first letter of second string in SharePoint calculated column?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I have a SharePoint list, where I got the first letter in a calculated column by using the `LEFT` function.

How can I get the first letter of a second string?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use following formula:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(" ",Title)),LEFT(REPLACE(Title,1,FIND(" ",Title),"")),"")
```

I took the assumption that you are using OOTB `Title` column and renamed to `User Name`. If you are using some different column then replace `Title` with your column's display name.

In case of single word, Above formula will show empty.

See output

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: If it worked for you then please mark this as answer so that it can be helpful to other in community

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula:

```
=LEFT(RIGHT([User Name],LEN([User Name])-INT(FIND(" ",[User Name]))))
```

**OR** (in case you might have leading or trailing or no space in the user name):

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(" ",TRIM([User Name]))),LEFT(RIGHT([User Name],LEN([User Name])-INT(FIND(" ",[User Name])))),"")
```

**Output**:

[image]

---

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (it is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).
2. Use correct *display name* of your SharePoint columns in above formula.
3. Wrap column names inside `[]` if your column name has space in it. For example: `[My Column Name]`.

**Official Documentations**:

1. [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14))

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort and time

Comment: Is it working for you?

Comment: Hi @Chandrika, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) (by clicking the "checkmark" button underneath the vote buttons) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily, thanks!